# Summary page with react-redux: container or presentational component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-component

I'm building a Summary page for merchant activity in a marketplace with react and redux.

The application has already a structure where there is a "MerchantContianer" that fetch data from server and create a list of merchant and other data render, all is rendered with a "Merchant" component (stateless).
There is also a "ReviewsContainer", it fetches data from server and renders it with a "Review" component (stateless).

MerchantContainer and ReviewsContainer are both rendered when requested from the navbar using Routing.

Now in the Summary I want to show the MerchantContainer and the ReviewsContainer and I don't know if the Summary should be a simple stateless component, or if I need to refactor MerchantContainer and ReviewsContainer so that they are no longer containers but components that gets all the data from the "SummaryContainer".

Oh and the summary could be rendered by another high order component in a Dashboard-like structure, so same question, should the summary be a Container or the Dashboard Container should pass all the data to the summary?

So I think I can summarize to: It’s ok to have a bunch of containers connected to redux and then render those containers from a presentational container to reuse them in a different page of the application?

There is a pitfall for going with a presentational component rendering containers?

Comment: Redux may eliminate the division between stateful/stateless (smart/dummy) components because it takes care of business logic. Since you likely have workable piece of code, consider asking at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well It's more a structural dilemma, the code works but I wonder if in general is a correct approach

Comment: I wasn't able to imagine what the app looks like from the descriptions. Code descriptions don't work well. That's why https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a must on SO. Any way, that's a question for Code Review.

Comment: thank you, I will post the question with some code on codereview